# Composite indexes in SQL

Tags: sql, indexing

Let's say I have a table Person:

```
ID 
Name
Surname
DateOfBirth
```

And I have this composite index: `(Name, Surname)`

Do I have to create an implicit index for Name? e.g For a where clause like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person 
WHERE Name=?
```

Or it's not needed as the previous index will cover it?

Comment: No, you do not need another index.  Your composite index covers it.

Comment: Gordon is right. But if you want proof, check the execution plan.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Note that it will not work for `Surname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a separate index to query the `NAME` column, if the `NAME` column is the first column in your composite index. This is because your index is ordered by `NAME ASC, SURNAME ASC`, so if you want to look up a `NAME` value, your database can scan only the relevant parts of the index.

However, your index will be pretty useless if you filter by `SURNAME` only, in case of which the whole index would need to be traversed anyway.

This website explains this nicely:
http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys

Comment: His book is highly recommended (SQL Performance Explained, Markus Winand)